# How to add launch screen for iPhone 5 using Xcode 7

Tags: ios, launch-screen

I'm trying to make launch screens for my app with its target as iOS 9.2 in Xcode 7.2.  The new way of making the launch screen for iPhones 6 and 6s is to use launch files which I am doing.  I would like to support iPhone 5 and 4s as well.  Apple says in their guide that for those two phones I need to use images with the specified requirements: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

I tried to use the asset catalog to add images for the older iPhones.  But the templates are not based on iPhone model like 5 or 4s, they are based on the iOS version like iOS 8, 7, and 6.  I don't know which template to use for iPhone 5 and 4s.  In other words which iOS target would be the right choice for those phones.  Thanks!

Comment: If your deployment target is iOS 8.0 or later, you just need the one launch screen file. It will work on all devices. You don't need launch images.

Comment: Thanks!  Since they said to use an image for iPhone 5 and 4s in the table in the link above I thought I should use the combination of both approaches.

Comment: @rmaddy Would you like to write your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to support all devices and your deployment target is iOS 8.0 or later, all you need is a single launch screen file. You do not need any launch images.

The launch screen file will signal iOS that your app supports all iPhone sizes and if it is a Universal app (or an iPad app) it signals iOS that is supports all iPad sizes.